# Installed Ubuntu 14.04 and my Windows 8.1 is gone now

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 as a dual boot with my Acer laptop which already had windows 8.1 pre installed. But when I finished installing Ubuntu, my Windows is gone which is no more now.

I need to factory reset my laptop to get Windows OS back. But when I try to reset it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> I'm prompted with some options like boot Ubuntu and memory test options were there.

Can anyone please guide me on how to restore my Windows 8.1 back? Is this is possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: In the likely case you did not overwrite your **recovery partition** with data you may be able to restore it using testdisk (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu). As the individual settings vary considerably we can not give an always-working guide here. By following the [step by step guide from TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) you may be able to succeed. If not, you will need a Windows CD/USB for restoring Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you accidentally chose to use the whole disk for Ubuntu. When you cannot see a Windows boot entry in the GRUB boot menu you mentioned - you unfortunately have to reinstall Windows. As you said that you just installed Ubuntu, I recommend to first install Windows and then Ubuntu.

You need a Windows installation media to do this. After you have finished the installation, reduce the Windows partition with GParted from the Ubuntu installation media - create a new partition from the unallocated space and format it with ext4 - then start the Ubuntu installer and choose **Something else** when asked and install Ubuntu to the new ext4 partition you created before.